# Node js, Call WebSocket server from oracle apex

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle-apex

I am trying to create web-sockets in APEX for automatic refresh with node

but I am getting error This is not valid JSON:

**java script code**

```js
$(function(){
  window.WebSocket = window.WebSocket || window.MozWebSocket;

  if (!window.WebSocket) {
    console.log('Sorry websockets');
  }
  else {
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1337');

    connection.onerror = function (error) {
      console.log( 'Sorry, but there is some problem with your connection or the server is down.');
    };

    connection.onmessage = function (message) { 
      console.log(message.data);   
      try {
        var json = JSON.parse(message.data);

        if (json.message=='REFRESH') {
          gReport.pull();
        }
        else { 
          console.log(json.message);
        } 

      } 
      catch (e) {
        console.log('Thisnot valid JSON: ' + message.data);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid - what does message.data look like, paste it in here.

Comment: f?p=106:3:12636075528993::::::240 This is not valid JSON: {"message":"{\"message\":'REFRESH'}"}